# Using Service to broadcast to Controllers or 2 way bind to Service from Controllers

Tags: angularjs, architecture, angularjs-scope

I have an architecture question.

Let's say I have a notifications list that will be interacted with by many different type of controllers.

I know of 2 ways to do it, but can't seem to decide:

```
service("Notifications", function(){
    var self = this;
    self.notificaitons = [];

    self.getNotificaitons(){
    ...
    }

    self.updateNotification(){
    ...
    }

})

controller("Controller1", function(
    Notifications
){

    scope.Notifications = Notifications
})
```

> template.html

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in Notifications.notifications">

</div>
```

The first way we have the controllers using the Notifications service directly to interact with. The benefit of this is that this will enable 2 way binding, and thus any change that I make within the service will automatically propagate to the controllers.

The second way is like this:

```
service("Notifications", function(){
    var self = this;
    self.notificaitons = [];

    self.subscribe = function(scope, callback) {
        var handler = $rootScope.$on('notification-event', callback);
    };



    self.getNotificaitons(){
    ...
    $rootScope.$emit('notification-event');
    }

    self.updateNotification(){
    ...
    $rootScope.$emit('notification-event');
    }

})

controller("Controller1", function(
    Notifications
){

    self.setListener = function(){
        Notifications.subscribe($scope, self.getNotifications());
    };

    self.getNotifications = function(){
        $scope.notifications = Notifications.notifications;
    }


})
```

> template.html

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in notifications">

</div>
```

Here, we are using the Notifications service to broadcast to anyone who is listening. I like this way because it is more so decoupled, but at the same time it is more code and more maintenance.

Maybe someone has had more experience with this can tell me something.
I would really appreciate it.